# Get Wording from a different table with primary key

Tags: php, sql

I have a table registering shipment of goods from a factory to a client, in this table I only register the factory and client code, but I need their name to appear in my webpage.

I am using a mysqli statement to get my data from the table.
I am using a Mysql database on phphmyadmin on a raspbian server.

I don't want to change anything inside the sql table, I just want the change to appear on the webpage.

```
<?php
    require '../include/header.php';
    require '../include/dbhandler.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Gestion des contenant</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css" />
</head>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    echo'
<body>
<div><p> vue global des client </p></div>

    <form action="include/gestioncontenant.inc.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="clientName" placeholder="Nom du Client"/><br>
                <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Search</button>
    </form><br>';
        // Récupération de la table client
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `mouvement` WHERE 1";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql) && isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
            header("location: ../gestioncontenant.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else {
             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $clientName);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
             $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                echo '<table border="1">';
                echo "<tr><td>Code</td><td>Type</td><td>Date</td><td>Site de prod</td><td>Client</td><td>Contenant</td><td>Quantit&eacute;</td><td>Transporteur</td></tr>";  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<tr><td>{$row["mouvement_code"]}</td><td>{$row["mouvement_type"]}</td><td>{$row["mouvement_date"]}</td><td>{$row["site_code"]}</td><td>{$row["client_code"]}</td><td>{$row["contenant_code"]}</td><td>{$row["contenant_quantite"]}</td><td>{$row["transporteur_code"]}</td></tr>\n";
                  }
        }
             echo"</table><br>"; 
}?>
<a href="../home.php"> retour</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In the table "movement" I only have the Id (foreign key) of my client and factory (site) and I need to display the names. 
I am only using html and php but if their is a solution in javascript or other language I'll implement it. Thanks!

Comment: Your query does not have any parameters, so there is nothing to bind the data to. You also have an extra `}` at the end.

Comment: Yes I did not post all the code. But I don't think the rest is relevant for this question.

Comment: In this case it would be a good idea to post a little bit more of your code, because what we see is not a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explain a bit more what the other tables look like

Im gonna assume you have this table

MOVEMENT(
client_code,
site_code,
mouvement_code,
mouvement_type,
contenant_code, ETC)

now is 'client_code' the ID of the client ?
if yes, do you have another table like this ? :

CLIENT(client_name, client_code, ETC)

if yes, then you simply need to make a join on the clientID between the two tables in your request :

```
SELECT a.*, b.client_name FROM `mouvement`a
left join 'client' b on a.client_code = b.client_code
WHERE conditions
```

then $row['client_name'] will be defined and you will be able to put it in your table

EDIT :

so if you have other tables

CONTENANT(contenant_name, contenant_code, ETC),

SITE(site_name, site_code, ETC),
 query becomes :

```
SELECT a.*, b.client_name, c.contenant_name, d.site_name FROM `mouvement`a
left join 'client' b on a.client_code = b.client_code
left join 'contenant' c on a.contenant_code = c.contenant_code
left join 'site' d on a.site_code = d.site_code
WHERE conditions
```

Comment: Tanks that's pretty much the case, but my issue is wis the other part: $row["site_code"] , $row["client_code"] , $row["contenant_code"] and $row["transporteur_code"] need to be replace by their name and they come from different table

Comment: Its the same principle of joining your table containing the IDs to the other tables with similar IDs
I edited main answer

Comment: I've tried it, it work but it is not what I wanted, I don't want to change anything inside the sql table, I just want the change to appear on the webpage.

Comment: When you make a SQL query, it creates a table based on what u ask in the query. Then in PHP you retrieve that table and get the fields you want from it. It didnt change anything in your database, it just created a "temporary" table so that u can use it, its not saved. I dont understand your problem ?

Maybe its the functions youre using in PHP, just use mysqli_query($link, $query) to execute the query, and get the results with while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))

Comment: I've noticed, I was testing the code directly on the db that's why I thought it would modifie the actual sql table. However my webpage table isn't modified and I don't get why. The code is working on the sql editor. I'm going to test with mysqli_query

Comment: I've tried this`if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo "<tr> ... </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<tr> ... </tr>\n";}` it doesn't displayAnythingNow.

Comment: Ha i see the issue, sorry i dont use your PHP mysqli library. 
You need to use "mysql_fetch_assoc()" instead of "mysql_fetch_row()", Basically the only difference between the two is that fech_assoc() keeps the name of the columns, while fetch_row() names the colums as '0,1,2, etc'

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc();` doesn't return anything, however it work with mysqli. But where back to the same issue where it doesn't show any modification.

Comment: my bad, I didnt left enough place for the new row to show up.

Comment: Merci de ton aide ;)